# Issue with gnm() and Dref() in R

Tags: r

I am working with a dataset Sey518, and my outcome variable is `R_SDNN` (continuous). I want to model it using the gnm function in R. The dataset contains two variables, `m107_f` and `y19_f`, which are categorical quartiles representing socioeconomic status (SES) at 107 months and 19 years, respectively. The possible values for both variables are: Low, MidLow, MidHigh, and High.

Here's the code I used:

```
# Loading required libraries
library(gnm)

# Model 1: Using Dref without upward and downward
drm_SDNN = gnm(R_SDNN ~ Dref(m107_f, y19_f), family = gaussian, data = Sey518)
DrefWeights(drm_SDNN)
```

further, I added upward and downward variables to the dataset based on a comparison between m107 and y19. If m107 is less than y19, upward is set to 1; otherwise, it's set to 0. Similarly, if m107 is greater than y19, downward is set to 1; otherwise, it's set to 0.

```
# Creating upward and downward variables
Sey518$upward = ifelse(Sey518$m107 < Sey518$y19, 1, 0)
Sey518$downward = ifelse(Sey518$m107 > Sey518$y19, 1, 0)

# Model 2: Using Dref with upward and downward
drm_SDNN_mob = gnm(R_SDNN ~ Dref(m107_f, y19_f, delta = downward + upward), family = gaussian, data = Sey518)
```

I encounter the following error: "Error in eval(x) : object 'downward' not found."

Could anyone kindly explain the warning in the first model and help me understand the coefficients Dref(m107_f, y19_f)delta1 and Dref(m107_f, y19_f)delta2? Additionally, I would appreciate guidance on how to resolve the error in the second model when using Dref with delta.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!